# Yii import data from excel file

Tags: php, excel, import, yii

I 'm not able to import data from excel file. `Yii` was also not showing any errors regarding this. Whenever I try to import the data from the excel the data is imported and also displays in the column which I have specified but I'm not able to update the database.
when I try to check the log files for the errors, there are no errors regarding the database updation. I don't know where it goes wrong.

```
public function importStuData($model)
    {

    $dispResults = []; 
    $totalSuccess = 0;

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($model->importFilePath.$model->importFile);
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    //print_r($sheetData); exit;
    unset($sheetData[1]);

    //start import student row by row
    foreach($sheetData as $k => $line){
        //print_r($line); exit;
        if(!array_filter($line))
            continue;

        $line = array_map('trim', $line);
        $line = array_map(function($value) { return empty($value) ? NULL : $value; }, $line);

        $stuMaster = new StuMaster();
        $stuInfo = new StuInfo();
        $stuInfo->scenario = 'import-stu';
        $stuAddress = new StuAddress();
        $user = new User();     
        $auth_assign = new AuthAssignment();

        //set student info attributes
        $stuInfo->stu_unique_id = $stuInfo->getUniqueId();  // Student Unique Id
        $stuInfo->stu_title = $this->valueReplace($line['A'], $stuInfo->getTitleOptions()); //Title Name 
        $stuInfo->stu_first_name = $line['B']; //First Name
        $stuInfo->stu_last_name = $line['C']; //Last Name 
        $stuInfo->stu_dob = Yii::$app->dateformatter->getDateFormat($line['D']); //Date of Birth
        $stuInfo->stu_admission_date = Yii::$app->dateformatter->getDateFormat($line['H']); //Student Admission Date
        $stuInfo->stu_gender = $this->valueReplace($line['I'], $stuInfo->getGenderOptions()); // Gender
        $stuInfo->stu_email_id = $line['J']; // Email ID
        $stuInfo->stu_mobile_no = $line['K']; // Mobile No

        //set student master attribute
        $stuMaster->stu_master_course_id = $this->valueReplace($line['E'], Courses::getStuCourse()); // Course
        $stuMaster->stu_master_batch_id = $this->valueReplace($line['F'], Batches::getStuBatches()); // Batch           
        $stuMaster->stu_master_section_id = $this->valueReplace($line['G'], Section::getStuSection()); // Section   
        $stuMaster->stu_master_category_id = $this->valueReplace($line['L'], StuCategory::getStuCategoryId()); //Admission Category

        $stuMaster->stu_master_nationality_id = $this->valueReplace($line['M'], Nationality::getNationality()); //Nationality

        //set student address attribute
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd = $line['N']; //Current Address
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_city = $this->valueReplace($line['O'], City::getAllCity()); //City
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_state = $this->valueReplace($line['P'], State::getAllState()); //State
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_country = $this->valueReplace($line['Q'], Country::getAllCountry()); //Country
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_pincode = $line['R']; //Pincode
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_house_no = $line['S']; //House No
        $stuAddress->stu_cadd_phone_no = $line['T']; //Phone No

        //set user login info attributes
        $uniq_id = $stuInfo->getUniqueId();
        $login_id = \app\models\Organization::find()->one()->org_stu_prefix.$uniq_id;

        $user->user_login_id = $login_id; //user login id
        $user->user_password = md5($user->user_login_id.$user->user_login_id); //user password
        $user->user_type = "S"; //user type
        $user->created_by = Yii::$app->getid->getId();  //created by        
        $user->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'); //created at

        if($user->validate() && $stuInfo->validate() && $stuAddress->validate())
        {               
            $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try{
                if($stuInfo->save() && $user->save() && $stuAddress->save()){

                    $stuMaster->stu_master_stu_info_id = $stuInfo->stu_info_id;
                    $stuMaster->stu_master_user_id = $user->user_id;
                    $stuMaster->stu_master_stu_address_id = $stuAddress->stu_address_id;
                    $stuMaster->created_by = Yii::$app->getid->getId();
                    $stuMaster->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
                    if($stuMaster->save()){

                        $stuInfo->stu_info_stu_master_id = $stuMaster->stu_master_id;
                        if($stuInfo->save(false)){
                            $auth_assign->item_name = 'Student';
                            $auth_assign->user_id = $user->user_id;
                            $auth_assign->created_at = date_format(date_create(),'U');
                            $auth_assign->save(false);
                            $transaction->commit();
                            $totalSuccess+=1;
                            $dispResults[] = array_merge($line, ['type' => 'S', 'stuMasterId' => $stuMaster->stu_master_id, 'message' => 'Success']);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $dispResults[] = array_merge($line, ['type' => 'E', 'message' => Html::errorSummary($stuMaster)]);                          
                    }
                } // end stuInfo, user, StuAddress
                $transaction->rollback();
            }
            catch(\Exception $e){
                $transaction->rollBack();
                $dispResults[] = array_merge($line, ['type' => 'E', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
            }                   
        }else{
            $dispResults[] = array_merge($line, [
                    'type' => 'E', 
                    'message' => Html::errorSummary([$user,  $stuInfo, $stuMaster, $stuAddress]),
                ]);
        }  //end validated if   
    } //end foreach
    return ['dispResults' => $dispResults, 'totalSuccess' => $totalSuccess];
}
```

Comment: still cant able to find the solution

Comment: I would suggest splitting up the validate() and save() into separate lines for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: Thats a nice suggestion...thanks for the advice...i will try it..